# Animate div using jQuery and changing the Width

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to slide in a div into the page while the page is loaded completely, I used CSS before, but it wasn't smooth at all, so i switched to use jQuery.

It's very smooth but i have a small issue which i believe somebody with more experience could solve it very quickly.

If you look at my output, the effect is not very seamless and it seems it stuck at some point.
Because i'm animating the div within change the width, i'm sure there is a better way to do that.

Here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#thumbnails").animate({
        opacity: 1,
        width: "800px",
  }, {
    duration: 500,
    specialEasing: {
    width: "linear"
    }
  });
});
```

Here is the Output link

```
http://jsbin.com/cuvaxuji/1
```

Comment: the effect is not very seamless and it seems it stuck at some point => means ?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/cuvaxuji/2 looks smooth to me. Also in slo-mo: http://jsbin.com/cuvaxuji/4

Comment: @blex Looks smooth to me as well, my problem is because i used changing width, the images are reordering during the animation, do you know i mean? I would like to slide the whole rendered UL not rendering them while the animation is applying.

Comment: Maybe you'd be better off animating the children at the same time if you want it to look nicer

Comment: can we see your css version? CSS should be significantly smoother than JQuery for animation.

Comment: @nepeo `-webkit-animation: slidebar 0.5s forwards;
    animation: slidebar 0.5s forwards;
}
 @-webkit-keyframes slidebar {
     100% { left: 240; }
 }

 @keyframes slidebar {
     100% { left: 240; }
 }`
When you have small content it works fine, but when your content is heavy(like tons of images and text) it's not smooth at all.

Comment: Hmm it's likely that the browser is dropping the frame rate to deal with the large reflows/draws. Have you tried using css 3D translate on your content with an overflow container for clipping? Will move your content to the GPU layer for processing. Might work better or could work exactly the same depending on where the exact bottleneck is... Incidentally 2D translate moves the content between the CPU and GPU layer depending on wether it's animating or not, which is a bit of a lag monster( so use the 3D one!!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to slide the div  ... for sliding make "#thumbnails" position absolute and write

```
  $("#thumbnails").animate({
        opacity: 1,
        left: "20px",
  }
```